# Retrieving the context (sentences) from Pinecone

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers, vector-database

I am building an open book abstractive QA model using Pinecone and Sentence Transformers, but I am having trouble later recalling the sentences that produced the matching vectors.

I thought I could store this context as metadata, like this:

```
with open("content.processed.json", "r") as f:
    documents = json.load(f)

model = SentenceTransformer('multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1')

qa = [{'id': str(uuid.uuid4()), 'content': doc['content'], 'encodings': model.encode(doc['content']).tolist()} for doc
      in documents]

pinecone.init(API_KEY, environment='us-west1-gcp-free')

index = pinecone.Index('httyl-index')
upserts = [(v['id'], v['encodings'], {'content': v['content']}) for v in qa]
for i in tqdm(range(0, len(upserts), 50)):
    i_end = i + 50
    if i_end > len(upserts):
        i_end = len(upserts)
    index.upsert(vectors=upserts[i:i_end])
```

Later, on retrieving these contexts, I am unable to get access to the sentences:

```
xq = model.encode(query).tolist()

xc = index.query(xq, top_k=5)
ids = [x['id'] for x in xc['matches']]
contexts = index.fetch(ids=ids)

model_name = 'deepset/electra-base-squad2'
nlp = pipeline(tokenizer=model_name, model=model_name,
               task='question-answering')

for context in contexts:
    print(nlp(
        f"question: {query} context: {context.content}",
        do_sample=True,
        temperature=0.8,
        max_length=64
    ))
```

The error is actually around an index, so perhaps this syntax is entirely incorrect, but this is like my 1,011th iteration of this code. The error produces is:

> pinecone.core.client.exceptions.ApiAttributeError: FetchResponse has no attribute '0' at ['['received_data']']

I need to iterate over those contexts and provide the original sentences to the pipeline. I intend to split this into two at some point, so the original sentences won't necessary be available.

How do I accomplish this? I imagined the metadata, including the original sentences, would be returned as metadata.

(I should point out I have never done Python in my life)

Comment: Did you find the answer to your query? I'd like to know the solution to this as well.